# Find created POD name from JOB name using Kubernetes/OpenShift API

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I want given a Job name find name of created Pod by Job controller using the OpenShift or Kubernetes REST API.

Using the CLI, this is possible by doing:

```
$ oc describe job testapi | grep -A 4 Events
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From            Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----            -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  6m    job-controller  Created pod: testapi-gff8c
```

Can we do same operation using the REST API?

I would like to get Pod names to get logs of all pods generated by a Job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The describe command is aggregating multiple results to provide its output so you will need to do a bit of extra work.

Call the `events` endpoint and parse the results using a tool like jq or can be pulled out in part by grep.

Heres an example assuming the job name is `testapi` and the namespace is `myproject`:

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(oc whoami -t)" -k https://127.0.0.1:8443/api/v1/namespaces/myproject/events?fieldSelector=involvedObject.name%3Dtestapi%2CinvolvedObject.namespace%3Dmyproject%2CinvolvedObject.kind%3DJob | grep Created`

Comment: Indeed! To be iso-functional with oc describe,  I would add we should match Job UID with "involvedObject.uid". This is for the case we created several job with same name. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, and likely pipe to jq for accurate parsing of results